# Is there a Libreoffice Calc function to translate languages?

Tags: libreoffice, functions

Is there a Libreoffice Calc function to translate languages? I would like to write words into my spreadsheet and then automatically copy and translate them into german into a new cell.

Comment: This is a duplicate of question asked in May 2016 but that question has no answers so this question should not be closed as duplicate I guess??? http://askubuntu.com/questions/769147/language-translate-function-for-libreoffice-calc-to-apply-to-a-cell

Comment: I guess basically it would be the same question.

Comment: I did a little googling but couldn't find an answer. I'll give your question a +1 and hopefully someone notices it who can answer.

Comment: I have no idea how to make this work in practice (and in may not) but it is at least _theoretically_ possible to use Calc to query a web resource to process the translation, and retrieve the result.

Google translate can be used in [API mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shahpiyush/2007/06/09/translate-your-text-using-google-apis/), and might offer a path to a solution.

Comment: In addition to @vandem's comment: in the Apache OOo forums, there's an [example how to query a web service](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=80996#p373618) that may be useful.